# JSON node in node js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Cube' of undefined

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to read the value of Currency of every country and their respective values from this `JSON` in `node.js` but every time i read the values i get this error. Can somebody point me to right way of reading key value pairs of nested `JSON` structure?

Comment: which country's value you want to access?

Comment: Isn't Cube inside "gesmes:Envelope" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your following line:

```
var Currency = parsedResponse.gesmes.Cube[0][1][0].currency;
```

with this line:

```
var Currency = parsedResponse['gesmes:Envelope']['Cube'][0]['Cube'][0]['Cube'][0]['$'].currency;
```

You will get currency `USD`.